# How MongoDB can return the data only to specific Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, mongoose

I want to know that How MongoDB can contact to specific node.

Lets say we have 2 nodejs server with same configuration that can contact with MongoDB. Now if I want to make the security on MongoDB that if request comes from Primary Node server then it response, else secondary request for database, MongoDB deny the request.

Is it possible to make some rules or anything by which we can achieve this..?

Any response for this post is really appreciated.

Comment: You could set up the firewall on mongo machines to reject the unwanted node server

Comment: is there any specific things on mongo besides this firewall securities

Comment: Depends on what exacty you need this for.